# getting system.ArgumentNullException on FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, repository

As I cant add the whole code here i am posting justa snippet.
I am getting and exception "System.ArgumentNullException"and an error that can't implicitly convert from Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet_Result to Project_List. I have started getting this error when i added last argument as null (after ST). Please help me with knowing what exactly is the issue as even in the database i have set this particular field as Allow null.

```
Project_List objProject_List = new Project_List();
objProject_List.Proj_Bill_ID = Convert.ToInt32(PID);

objProject_List = _OCB.Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet
                   ( Convert.ToInt32(PID), TID, RID, ECY
                   , TT, Convert.ToDateTime(GD), Convert.ToDateTime(SD)
                   , Convert.ToDateTime(EED), Convert.ToDateTime(ED)
                   , null, Convert.ToDecimal(TP), Convert.ToDecimal(TE)
                   , Convert.ToDecimal(TDA), Convert.ToDecimal(TR), TCR, ST, null
                   ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Then `_OCB.Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet` returns null.

Comment: @PatrickHofman so u mean its returning null so the exception?

Comment: That is what I said, right?

Comment: what can be the workaround for this? As i was not facing this issue previously.. After i set last argument as null i started getting the error

Comment: Not returning null.

Comment: I would suggest do not store it directly in `objProject_List`. First create a `var` which will hold the output of your expression. Then you check if it is not null and `count` is more than `0`. Plus, in the if condition you should also check if the `FirstOrDefault()` of `var` is `Project_List`. I would suggest the code in answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If this Exception occurs after adding last null parameter, than you should go to the method Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet and check how this parameter is treated. There are 2 possibilities:

1. The system does not accept null as a parameter
2. Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet(...) returns null

To fix 1st case you need to override Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet(...) logic so null will be acceptable or provide not null value.

To fix 2nd case you could change expression to:

```
objProject_List = _OCB.Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet(...)?.FirstOrDefault();
```

In this case `objProject_List` will be null if `_OCB.Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet(...)` returns null

Answer (score 0):

Code restructure suggestion:

```
Project_List objProject_List = new Project_List();
objProject_List.Proj_Bill_ID = Convert.ToInt32(PID);

var projList = _OCB.Ins_ProjectTestCycleDet(Convert.ToInt32(PID), TID, RID, ECY,
               TT, Convert.ToDateTime(GD), Convert.ToDateTime(SD), Convert.ToDateTime(EED), Convert.ToDateTime(ED), null
               , Convert.ToDecimal(TP), Convert.ToDecimal(TE), Convert.ToDecimal(TDA), Convert.ToDecimal(TR), TCR, ST, null);

if(projList != null
   && projList.Count > 0
   && projList.FirstOrDefault() is Project_List)
{
    objProject_List = projList.FirstOrDefault();
}
```